# how to parse a JFR file in Oracle JDK7 or JDK8 programatically?

Tags: java, java-8, jfr

The API for **Oracle JDK14, and JDK15** is published at https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jfapi/parsing-recording-file.html
but I couldn't find similar documentation for Oracle JDK8.

I was wondering if someone was able to print out the list of events for a JFR file collected with JDK8, just like in the example shown by the docs for JDK14, and JDK15. In that case, what is the role of **<jdk1.8>\jre\lib\jfr.jar** file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for JDK8 was posted by Marcus in an external site:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import oracle.jrockit.jfr.parser.*;

public class JDKParserTest {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File recordingFile = new File("C:\\demo\\wldf.jfr");
        Parser parser = new Parser(recordingFile);
        int count = 0;
        Iterator<ChunkParser> chunkIter = parser.iterator();
        while (chunkIter.hasNext()) {           
            ChunkParser chunkParser = chunkIter.next();
            for (FLREvent event : chunkParser) {
                count++;
                //System.out.println(event.toString());
            }
        }
        parser.close();
        System.out.println("Found " + count + " events");
    }
}
```

That's exactly what I needed to build a custom report.
Ref: http://hirt.se/blog/?p=446

Answer (score 1):

The JFR related classes in the parsing example exist since [Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.jfr/jdk/jfr/Event.html), so it's not possible to do the example in Java 8 or earlier (at least without a lot of trickery).

The `jfr.jar` contains the Java Flight Recorder [runtime](http://jar.fyicenter.com/3392_JRE_7_jfr.jar-JFR_%28Java_Flight_Recorder%29.html), so it's used for collecting the data, not parsing it.

Answer (score 1):

The parser API in Oracle JDK 8 is unsupported and undocumented, but if you just want to print a recording to standard out you can try:

```
$ java oracle.jrockit.jfr.parser.Parser [-xml] <file>
```

If you want to do anything more complicated on older releases, I would look into the JMC parser, which supports both Oracle JDK 8 and the new file format added in JDK 9.

https://github.com/openjdk/jmc